# Angular Momentum Quantum Number and Orbitals

Tags: orbitals

In our lecture I was told the angular momentum QN is equal to  $n - 1$ of the principle QN, which corresponded to the orbital shape.  How is this case, for example in Barium the principle QN is 6 with, so it should have at least an f orbital because the angular momentum QN contains 3, which corresponds to the f orbital, but in it's electron configuration it does not have an f orbital. Why is this?

Comment: "*In our l*"? what was this supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has the f orbitals, they're just empty, and so they get left out of the (ground state) electron configurations.

F orbitals are high energy orbitals for their energy level.  The 4f orbitals (in n=4) don't get filled until after the 6s orbital is filled (and kinda sorta one 5d gets filled - f orbitals don't really follow nice patterns when they get filled).

For a good read on the filling pattern of orbitals (which, btw, is very much a generalization - there are plenty of exceptions), here's a [good link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Chemistry/Filling_Electron_Shells).